# having problem with Full Screen mode in browser in my react Project

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, browser

I have a react project for shopping, there is a sticky basket button at bottom of the page. by scrolling to the top and bottom, the sticky button jumps up because of full-screen mode in the browser.
P.S: by full-screen mode I mean when the URL disappears by scrolling.
how can I fix it?

````
position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;```
````

Answer (score 0):

you can add position property to fixed

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: then try `position: sticky`